# L_ERRORCODE0: 10501 while connecting to paypal do direct

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

We are trying to make a transaction using the paypal API for do direct.We encounter the following error when we submit the details.Went through various links and questions,and everyone suggested to activate the **Website Payments Pro** for example [here](http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.in/2010/03/paypal-10501-failure-in-transaction.html).
But,if I check my account there is no such section on the left and neither do I have  Website Payments Pro option anywhere.

```
PayPal API Error
The PayPal API has returned an error!
TIMESTAMP:  2013-04-03T06:36:34Z
CORRELATIONID:  d0f6f7281495d
ACK:    Failure
VERSION:    98.0 
BUILD:  5479129
L_ERRORCODE0:   10501
L_SHORTMESSAGE0:    Invalid Configuration
L_LONGMESSAGE0: This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration.
L_SEVERITYCODE0:    Error
AMT:    200.00
CURRENCYCODE:   USD
```

I am not sure if there is any other solution,so would like any help from the members on it.Currently working with a sandbox account for testing.API version I am working on is 98.0

Answer (score 2):

This error means that Website Payments Pro is not enabled.  I have modified the account and added pro on to it.  Please try running another test and see if it goes through now.

Comment: Thank you for the help.How to enable it?I did not find the option anywhere under the account section!!Can you add the steps please?I got it working by adding a new buisness account through a new user.